# Игнорирование всех пробелов, кроме спецсимволов &nbsp;

Tags: html, css

Есть следующие элементы:

```
<div>
  <span>example1, example2, example3</span>
  <span>,example4 ,example5, example6</span>
</div>
```

Нужно сделать так чтобы все пробелы (кроме спецсимволов) в div и span-ах игнорировались, при этом чтобы переносы работали как обычно. Результат нужно получить как в такой аналогии:

```
<div><span>example1,example2,example3</span><span>,example4,example5,example6</span></div>
```

Только сам код должен быть оформлен как в примере выше. Как это можно сделать, т.к. white-space здесь не подходит?

P.S. В планах пробелы размещать с помощью `&nbsp;`, дабы их можно было контролировать.

Comment: А как это можно сделать с помощью js, ведь там уже &nbsp; учитывается как обычный пробел?

Comment: Т.е. например после загрузки html, обработать это js-ом?

Comment: **Вас вводят в заблуждение**, ни php ни NodeJS не помогут изменить отображение(не меняя исходного кода). т.к. у вас требование изменить только внешность - то у вас верно указаны тэги, при этом мне не известно возможно ли изменить отрисовку конкретного символа. скорей всего надо смотреть в сторону кастомных шрифтов, в которых есть только неразрывный пробел но нет обычного(точнее он имеет нулевую ширину)

Comment: @UbuntuUser Я лишь указал что вы вводите человека в заблуждение, мне не известно имеет ли задача решение или нет, но я точно могу сказать что **под его требования ваши советы - вредны** (требование не менять вид исходного кода, но поменять стили отображение)

Comment: @UbuntuUser Вред в том что ваш совет **нарушает одно из требований** (не менять вид исходного кода) и **не сообщаете об этом ни слова**. Вариант решения(один из возможных) я уже указал в комментарии, кастомный шрифт в котором пробелы и не нужные символы имеют нулевую ширину. **пробел** и **неразрывный пробел** - **разные символы**